# forEach loop not looping correctly

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, foreach, asyncstorage

i have the following code:

```
array.forEach(function(x){
  console.log("inside foreach")

  const getData = async () => {
  try {
   const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("item")
   if(jsonValue != null){

   console.log("not null")

   }else{

   console.log("null")

   }
   }
   getData()
})
```

it doesn't work properly, the output retrieves first all the "inside foreach" and then the rest. How can I fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Use a `for..of` loop instead and `await` each async call

Comment: To execute the operations in parallel use `Promise.all` to execute them sequentially use `Array.prototype.reduce`, a `for..await..of` loop, or something else.